# 'ValueError: Image with id {} already added' When Run Evaluation on OpenImage Dataset

Tags: python, validation, tensorflow, neural-network, object-detection-api

I am using Tensorflow Object Detection API to evaluate the SSD_mobilenet model on OpenImageV5 dataset. I used the pretained model provided in their [model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md). 
For the pipeline config, I am using the default pipeline (`ssd_mobilenet_v2_oid_v4`) available [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs).

When I run the evaluation using following command:

```
python object_detection/model_main.py --alsologtostderr --run_once --checkpoint_dir=/Path/TO/ssd_mobilenet_v2_oid_v4_2018_12_12/ --model_dir=eval/ --pipeline_config_path=PATH/TO/ssd_mobilenet_v2_oid_v4.config
```

I get this error:

```py
2019-05-28 12:26:09.658946: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1306] Invalid argument: ValueError: Image with id 1407414044 already added.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/bigSSD/tensorflow_model/v_env_tf_1.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 157, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/bigSSD/tensorflow_model/models/research/object_detection/utils/object_detection_evaluation.py", line 432, in update_op
    self.add_single_ground_truth_image_info(image_id, single_example_dict)

  File "/bigSSD/tensorflow_model/models/research/object_detection/utils/object_detection_evaluation.py", line 600, in add_single_ground_truth_image_info
    raise ValueError('Image with id {} already added.'.format(image_id))

ValueError: Image with id 1407414044 already added.
```

I changed `sample_1_of_n_examples` from 10 to 100 and 1000 but still got the same error.

Comment: could you paste your config file here, especially in `eval_config`, the `num_examples` should be equal to your evaluation dataset size.

Comment: `num_examples` is deprecated and I don't have it in the config file.
I used the sample config file provided by the object detection api ([here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v2_oid_v4.config))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid_v4.config I changed

```
eval_config 
{
  metrics_set: "open_images_V2_detection_metrics"
}
```

to

```
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "open_images_V2_detection_metrics"
  num_examples: 383 #correspond to my test images
}
```

then run the evaluation with eval.py using the following command:

```
python eval.py --logtostderr --checkpoint_dir=path/to/checkpoint --eval_dir=path/to/eval_dir --pipeline_config_path=path/to/pretrained_model.config
```

and my error solved.